# Zod enum with generic array

Tags: typescript, generics, zod

For now if I try to use generic const for zod enum, it throws an error in typescript, saying that there is no `data` property in this object:

```
import { z } from 'zod';

function objectWithGenericEnum<T extends string>(
    options: readonly [T, ...T[]]
) {
    const a =  z.object({
        data: z.enum(options),
    });

    return a.transform((v) => v.data);
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgNwBQFmArgHYDGMwEdcEARgFYCmTA6sBgALAOI86PKMAYBROjRAAeACpweADxgTiAZzi6Y0ugHMAfAAoKcG%20zDNWugFxwoPAIbFWAGwCecAG0VABo4ADoIlQCAXWiKAEpEa1sGR3h3OABeG2Qwzl4mCwRk21tidxh3F1yJRQsIexY6XXjgkvR4yna3GBooNncwo3dmzGgQCwsAN0TMszgpsPLKzoo0CiA)

Any way to cast it properly somehow?

Comment: This seems like a bug and I submitted a report here: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/2077

Answer (score 0):

The author and another major contributor to the `zod` library [responded](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/2077) and explained:

> ZodEnum is designed to work with tuples of string literals ['a', 'b'], etc. In the generic context, the generic hasn't been literalized so inference is going to be tricky. As a workaround use a typecast: z.enum(options as [string, ...string[]])

And suggested:

```js
function objectWithGenericEnum<U extends string, T extends Readonly<[ U, ...U[] ]>> (
    options: T
) {
    const enumValidator = z.enum( options as any as [ string, ...string[] ] )
    const a = z.object( {
        data: enumValidator,
    } )
    return a.transform( ( v ) => v.data )
}
```

Comment: Well this solution is not fully working one, because in this case we will loose string literals in transform output, and it will be just string type.